# Valid way to represent mutation and similarity of outputs in an artificial neuron

Tags: notation, neural-networks

I am defining an activation function like below where F and w are vectors with an arbitrary dimension and φ is the activation function that squashes w x F to a smaller dimension:

[image: R_c (F_c)= φ_c (w_c x F_c)]

I then want to represent the similarity between *R* and *R'*, which is output of a mutation function applied to *R*:

[image]

This does not look right at all though. I am thinking about defining each value in *F* and *w* as vectors themselves (So instead of say F being an average of different simultaneous inputs, it would be a set of vectors where each vector is a different simultaneous input) and represent *φ* as a dot product with another vector. Not sure if that is the right approach either though.

[image]

[image]